# Web Scraping javascript in Python / R

Tags: javascript, python, html, r, web-scraping

I'm doing some personal data science projects and one of them is to see how often certain songs are played on the radio.

http://www.iheart.com/live/radio-1045-3401/

Looking at the above URL, when I look at page source, no values of interest populate. Not sure why, but when I use inspect element in chrome when I hover over the "Now Playing" header, I can see values for song and artist now playing.

Example:

```
a class="player-song" href="/artist/rem-3610/songs/-2450662/" title="Losing My Religion" data-reactid=".1hpdfx1l4ow.a.1.0.1.1">Losing My Religion</a
```

My two questions are:

1. Why isn't this showing up in page source, but I can see it under Inspect Element?
2. How would I web scrape this info since it is not appearing in page source?

Comment: haven´t checked but it´s probably content generated by javascript, in which case you could use selenium in python

Comment: you could probably also get the data using their API.. http://developer.iheart.com/Api/login

Answer (score 3):

1. Most web pages that involve dynamic elements have page elements generated and inserted by Javascript that the browser parses and executes for you. You already guessed this, I suspect, based on the question title.

   What you see in the page source is the raw HTML *before* Javascript kicks in and updates it.
2. You want a [headless browser](http://blog.arhg.net/2009/10/what-is-headless-browser.html): a browser without a graphical user interface. This will parse and execute Javascript for you, and update page HTML accordingly.

---

Here is a [full list of headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers). Note that you can do this task in any language.

Comment: MechanicalSoup states in their readme that it doesn't do javascript, and RoboBrowser is a mix of requests and beautifulSoup so I think not. Not sure about Mechanize too. Nice answer though.