# BeautifulSoup - access content on page that is loaded dynamically

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am writing a program that goes through this site: http://www.whatuni.com, 
specifically: http://www.whatuni.com/degree-courses/search?subject=software-engineering&pageno=
Pages 1 to 6.
It searches through every page and looks for every university that is Russell Group and does software engineering then looks through all modules. It is meant to reject any module with a hardware component and add the rest to a list. So far it is searching through the modules pages but there is a problem: The topics in the module in the website are not displayed by default, it is loaded by JavaScript after a button is pressed. This is a page that shows the situation:
http://www.whatuni.com/degrees/artificial-intelligence-and-software-engineering-beng-hons/university-of-edinburgh/cd/54977454/5508/
I want to know how I can access these modules so I can loop through them, it is the last complicated step in this program. Would I have to simulate user input or would that not work because it does not parse through the browser? Or do I have to look in a script? I am using python 3.4, and beautiful soup for this program.

```
from general import *

class ModuleCrawler:

base_url = ""
page_url = ""
bad_words = ("computer systems" or "computer architecture" or "hardware" or "electronics"
             or "information technology")

def __init__(self, base_url, page_url):
    self.base_url = base_url
    self.page_url = page_url
    self.crawl_topics(self.get_description(get_html(page_url)))

def crawl_topics(self, description):
    if self.bad_words in description.lower():
        print("crap uni")
    else:
        #print(description.lower())

    append_to_file("PossibleUnis.txt", self.page_url)

def get_description(self, html_string):
    return ', '.join(str(s) for s in (get_by_id(html_string, "#fullDesc")))
```

That is the module crawler, the beautiful soup code is in another file. I made it get the description from the page instead but that sometimes leaves out those words and my text file has many modules that have those topics.

Comment: Add your code so far, also what button are you talking about?

Comment: Open the third link and go down to where it says modules, most of them are not selected.

Comment: the third link where?

Comment: In my post, that is an example of a univercitiy's software engineering course and it shows how the modules have to be clicked on.

Comment: There are only two links in your post

Comment: The top is actually two links, they are quite close so I understand why they look like one.

Comment: Ah ok so the last link.  So when we visit the age what are we trying to simulate, which button click?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered umpteen times and should appropriately be listed as a duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506547/web-scraping-javascript-in-python-r

Comment: The plus button next to Modules (Year 2)

Comment: A headless browser sounds what I was looking for but I am unsure how to apply it.

Comment: Are you open to using selenium with phantomjs?

Comment: I think I would prefer to use selenium because I have heard of it before

Comment: Well selenium works well with phantomjs for headless scraping

Comment: How would I use it, can I still use it with beautifulsoup to return html>

Comment: Yes you can so both but selenium allows pretty much all css and xpath tag selectors, it also returns the source so you don'r need anything else. I think we could actually do it without if we put the query together manually, I am just looking at that now, if it does now work I can show you how to easily do it with selenium

Comment: Ok, I just downloaded both.

Comment: So, I am assuming that phantomjs is the browser that selenium is going to load?